# Javascript : addEventListener in for loops using number-ids

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I tried this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="elementbox"></div>

        </div>
        <script>
            var se
            for (var i=1; i<20; i++) {
                document.getElementById('elementbox').innerHTML +=
                     "<div id ="+i.toString()+" ><p>E</p><p>HTMLnb</p><p>"+i+"</p></div>";
                alert(document.getElementById(i.toString()).id);
                se = document.getElementById(i.toString());
                se.addEventListener('click', function() {
                    alert("you clicked");
                }, false);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried to use "alarm"s to  debug but I still cant find the error. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think there is an "error"?

Answer (score 1):

When you assign to `innerHTML`, the browser has to rebuild all DOM elements within that parent element. So on the 20th iteration, all of the previous `div` elements you'd bound event handlers to no longer exist in the DOM, and can therefore never respond to the click event.

```js
var container = document.getElementById("elementbox");
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = i;
    div.textContent = "Click Me (" + i + ")";
    (function(i) {
        div.addEventListener("click", function() {
            alert("clicked " + i);
        })
    })(i);
    container.appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<div id="elementbox"></div>
```

Just to explain further (because I'm sure you'll encounter this shortly), this bit:

```
(function(i) {
    div.addEventListener("click", function() {
      alert("clicked " + i);
    });
})(i);
```

Is to do with variable scoping in JavaScript. Without this inner function, the callback would be accessing the exact copy of `i` that the `for` loop is accessing (and changing)... which means every time you click you'll always get "clicked 20" because that's what `i` equals after the loop has finished running.

So this code creates an anonymous function and immediately calls it, passing in the current state of `i`. The `i` in the inner function is a new scope, and therefore won't change when the event handler call back eventually fires (by clicking the div). So when you fire the event handler, it will be accessing that copy of `i` that is created for each and every handler you're attaching.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: alerts are not firing in the snippet. Not sure if that is intentional.

Comment: They should be; click where it says "click me" :). Wait, it doesn't seem to work in Chrome (works in FF and IE). I'm getting an error in the console about `alert` not being allowed because of security on modal windows. Meh, here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nauzilus/e3pp1d1b/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding eventlisteners and divs one by one, you should try doing it one time to avoid DOM performance penalty. Once the elements are created on the DOM you can add all the event handlers. I haven't optimized this code so running a second loop to register all event handlers.

To remember loop variables, you will have to employ an IIFE or Immediately Invoked Function expression which takes in the loop counter and creates a private scope for that variable(a closure) which your event handler can access.

alerts are not firing in this snippet, so I have added a span tag to capture messages for each click.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var html = "";
  for (var i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
    html += "<div><a href='#' id ='" + i.toString() + "'>E HTMLnb " + i + "</a></div>";
  }
  document.getElementById('elementbox').innerHTML = html;

  for (var i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
    document.getElementById(i.toString()).addEventListener('click', (function(loopCnt) {
        return function() {
          document.getElementById("message").innerHTML += "<br>you clicked " + loopCnt;
      };
    }(i)), false);
  }
};
```

```html
<div id="elementbox"></div>

<span id="message"></span>
```